# How to remove separate login page in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I use devise gem for authentication of users in my rails app and I decide to use root page as login page. I fund solution, how to redirect user to root url if login unsuccessful (code below), but I can't find how tell to devise, that it should use root url for login page instead of separate login page on /users/sign_in

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    if warden_options[:scope] == :user
      root_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to display a login form in homepage or your full homepage is just a login form?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a login form for example in the header or every other page, you have to write your own form.
But you can copy the code of the normal devise login form.

To get the devise views you can write in console:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Then you can copy the devise login form from app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb and paste it in the view or in a partial.

This could be something like:

```
<%= form_for(User.new, :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
  <%= f.submit 'Sign in' %>
  <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path('user') %>
<% end %>
```

It's impotant that you change the variable to .new or you have to define the variable in the Controller you want to use the form. In my example I write User.new.

For more information, check out this HowTo:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Comment: Remember to post about the application_helper resources which need to be included to make this work

Comment: I've tested this solution in one of my rails projects and it works without any other configuration. What did you exactly mean?

Comment: Oh wait, you've used the form differently, sorry. By default, Devise calls an instance variable called "resource" on the form. This is how you can use the Devise gem for different models / controllers. The problem is that if you want to move your form onto a different model / controller, you need to be able to define the resource again. To remedy this, most people put the resource definitions into the application_helper.rb like this:

Comment: `#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
        def devise_resource_name
                :user
        end

        def devise_resource
                @resource ||= User.new
        end

        def devise_mapping
                @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
        end`

Answer (score 0):

If you've got your form working, you might be looking for info about the Devise routes, specifically about the paths:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :password => 'forgot', :confirmation => 'confirm', :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'register', :sign_up => 'new', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

More info here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes